# Convert formatted character string into unformatted character string with run-time user-defined format

Tags: fortran

> **Question:** How can I read variables from a string with run-time user-defined FORMAT and store a corresponding binary version of the variables in a character buffer where the types stem from the format?
>
> **Equivalent Question:** How can I convert a formatted string with run-time user-defined FORMAT into a string containing the corresponding bit-representation of the corresponding types defined by the format?

In short, we have a program that does some simple processing. The steps are:

1. Read a string from a file
2. Read a user-defined format from the file
3. Process the string with the format and store all variables in a character-buffer (in binary form)
4. Continue program

A simplified program would be:

```
program test
  implicit none
  character(len=16) :: string
  character(len=32) :: fmt
  character(len=8) :: buf1, buf2, buf3

  string = 'ABC 12  3.4'
  fmt = '(A3,1X,I2,1X,F4.1)'

  read(string,fmt) buf1,buf2,buf3
  write(*,'(A3,A4,A8)') buf1,buf2,buf3
end program
```

An example output, parsed by `od` could be:

```
$ ./a.out | od -t x1
0000000 41 42 43 0c 00 00 00 33 33 33 33 33 33 0b 40 0a
0000020
```

This output is system dependent. In this case, floats are assumed to be IEEE floating-point numbers, and the system runs as little-endian.
The sequence `41 42 43` represents `ABC`, the sequence `0c 00 00 00` represents 12 and `33 33 33 33 33 33 0b 40 0a` is the nearest double precision representation to the number 3.4.

The above program compiles and runs fine using the SolarisStudio Fortran compiler `f90` using the flags `-f77=input`.

```
$ f90 -f77=input file.f90
```

However, this is not standard Fortran. The read-format and the variables should match type. The GNU compiler quickly chokes on this:

```
$ gfortran file.f90
$ ./a.out 
At line 10 of file read_string.f90
Fortran runtime error: Expected INTEGER for item 2 in formatted transfer, got CHARACTER
(A3,1X,I2,1X,F4.1)
```

Is there a "simple" way to convert this in Standard Fortran or make it work in other compilers like the GNU/Intel/PGI Fortran compilers?

Comment: What do you anticipate the results being?  That is, if you read the `12` part into the character variable `buf2` do you want it to have value `"12"` or ASCII (etc.) 12, or for the bit-wise value of integer 12?  (I guess the final one, given the use of "3.4".)

Comment: Since you know the number of variable, why not go for a  `read(string,*) buf1,buf2,buf3` ? This will only work if there are blanks between your variables though.
Besides that, the "simplest" way would be to change the format, which seems logical since you're only storing character.

Comment: @francescalus I'm expecting that the buffers contain the corresponding bit-pattern of the respective type (provided by the format). We do not want the ASCII representation. That would be too easy. Also, the format can change from one execution to another. Format and strings are all user-defined at run-time.

Comment: One awkwardness is that a read processing `"3.4"` is interpreted by the type (including kind parameters) of the input item.  That is, `"3.4"` could be default real, double precision, radix 17, etc., depending on something else, with corresponding different bit representations.  Can you defined which representation is required?

Comment: @francescalus, we assume that the system processes it as is. If I have a system running in radix-10, then the output is radix-10. If it runs with 39-bit reals, then it are 39 bit reals.

Comment: @francescalus A similar problem would occur if I would like to write a program that can convert any data-table from one format to another. Where the input and output formats are input to the program.

Comment: Agreed.  However, 3.4 as a literal constant means one precise thing, but reading from "3.4" doesn't.  If you care only to treat the "3.4" as if it would be interpreted as a literal constant then that's a helpful clarification.

Comment: @francescalus the floating point numbers should be converted to the nearest possible representation.

Comment: (My comments are likely getting less helpful, so I'll stop after this one.)  If we have `read(str,'(F4.1)') x, y` with `str` value `" 3.4 3.4"` then the bitwise representations of `x` and `y` could be very different.  Which of those (or any other) would you choose?  The same, but to a lesser extent, holds for `"ABC"` and `"12"`.  I'd say "the default real" representation is most natural, but you mention IEEE double precision as desired.  (Sorry if I come across as needlessly pedantic.)

Comment: @francescalus you are not pedantic, you are in an attempt to understand my problem in the most generic way something which I greatly appreciate. As the question is not clear at this moment, there is clearly something wrong with the question. I'll attempt to rephrase the question completely in a more simple way. I'll close this question for the time being.

Comment: @francescalus and apparently I cannot do it myself. As a goldbatch, just hammer this question as unclear.

Comment: Someone may be able to answer with "this is _exactly_ how Sun Studio did it, and the equivalent in standard Fortran", so it'd be a little unfair to close as unclear just because the generalisation is tricky.  (I also can't golden hammer as unclear, just as duplicate.)  Let's see what everyone else thinks.